# Estimates of mean and variance

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose we know all the moments of  random variable exist and are non negative  but the values are known only for even order moments  of  random variable.(the pdf is not known)That is,suppose ,
$$E(X^{2r})=f(r)\geq0,\text{say}$$
WE can easily found a bound for $E(x)$ given by $$E(X) \leq \sqrt{E(X^2)} $$
My question is how good thisbound is ?can we find an estimate of variance?Any help\hints are highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bound is sharp, i.e. $$|E(X)|=\sqrt{E(X^2)}$$ if and only if $$Var(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2=0.$$ This is the case iff $X$ is almost surely constant. But I am guessing that this is why you where asking about an estimator for the variance since $$|E(X)|=\sqrt{E(X^2)-Var(X)}.$$ Are you looking for a statistical estimator from samples $(X_n)_{n=0,\dots,N}$, or an estimator from the known even moments?
For the former, check out [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation) estimator. For the latter, I can only think of a solution for the case that you know the underlying distribution. Then you could solve for the parameters from the theoretical moments. For example, if $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then $$E(X^2)=\mu^2+\sigma^2$$ and $$E(X^4)=\mu^4+6\mu^2\sigma^2+3\sigma^4.$$ If you know the values of those quantities you should be able to solve for $|\mu|$ and $\sigma^2$.

Comment: thank you for your awesome answer.I was ,btw,looking for the estimate from the known moments .Your answer is really helpful

Comment: To mee it seems magical and incredible that we can estimate mean and variance from the even moments only